# iPhone Create View Before TabBarController on tab bar application template

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I'm getting pretty good at using xcode and objective c, but only from the templates.

I wish my application to load to a view to login before it reaches the tab bar controller that i have set up.

I believe this can be done in the 'didfinishlaunchingwithoptions' section of the app delegate but after that I don't have any idea how once the login is successful that i can show the tab controller again.

i'll be grateful for any help :)

Comment: u want to show first show a view without using tabbar controller or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [modal views](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html) for this.
Sample example [here](https://github.com/ironfounderson/BookLibrary_Delegate).

Comment: after a little thought thats exactly what i did! thanks for your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this

```
    LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    [tabBarController presentModalViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];
```

inside didfinishlaunchingwithoptions